# How do i get a database table to JSON in php

Tags: php, mysql

i used this code

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password")
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$arr;

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("info",$dbhandle)
or die("Could not select examples");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $arr[]=$row;
}
```

Is it right way to store all data of a table into a 2D array.
And how i use this array in Ajax as json to show data in a HTML file.?

Comment: yes, whats your actual problem?

Comment: the other thing you could do is, you can create associative array for all students (by some primary key), to efficiently access students by id. like `$students[$row['stud_id']]=$row;`... and later access individual student records like, `$students[101]`

Comment: I want to use this array in Ajax as json to print it in a HTML page.
how i can?

Comment: Please rephrase you question to include your real question or it will get flagged.

Comment: @AniketSingh, check my answer. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in comments, that you want to do ajax and json.

You can do code like this (use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of array):

```
//set content type: text/json
header("Content-Type: text/json");

$dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password") or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("info",$dbhandle) or die("Could not select examples");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
    $rows=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $rows[]=$row;
    }
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>$rows));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array("error"=>"No records found."));
}
exit;
```

and for ajax (assuming, [jQuery.get() AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/))

```
$.get("script.php", function(data){
    if(data.success){
        //process each row
        data.success.forEach(function(row){
            console.log(row); //access student row here, simply like row.student_name, row.city etc.
        });
    }else{
        alert(data.error);
    }
});
```

**Scurity Note:**

1. [**mysql_* functions are deprecated and will be removed from support**, so you should avoid using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli).
2. use [**mysqli_***](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for database queries.

Comment: Thanks
Yes it working when i using data as a 2d array like this
     for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        $("p").append("ID"+data[i].s_id+"Name"+data[i].name);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $arr[]=$row; 
}
```

Check [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) documentation for more information. However, its recommended that you use PDO or MySQLi drivers as this is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.